# JSON class couldn't handle arabic words

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8

I am  using JSON class in my application. But, I am having an issue with the arabic alphbet. Whenever I try to WRITE to my database I get ?????? for arabic. For English it is no problem. I have setchar in my php to be compatible with  utf-8 and as well in the database, the field is utf-general-ci. But, I think the problem is with my JSON class. Here is my JSON class.

```
public class JSONParser {

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> pairs)
{
    try
    {
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeoutConnection = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeoutConnection);

        int timeoutSocket = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        if (pairs != null)
        {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs) );
        }

        HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (httpEntity != null)
        {
            String ret = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            return new JSONObject(ret.substring(ret.indexOf("{"), ret.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I believe it is using the default Encryption. How can I fix it to be UTF-8. Well, in the line with I use http.Post.setEntity , I tried to make "UTF-8" as another parameter in the method setEntity. It is giving me an error. So, do you have any suggestions???? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
String ret = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

with this line

```
 String ret = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

maybe its not the json but the HttpClient